# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference. App crashes on run

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Need help with this error log. Trying to create a food delivery app and here is the source code of said application on Android Studio. The application keep on crashing every time I run the application.:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.swiftbites.Adapters.OrdersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(OrdersAdapter.java:43)
        at com.example.swiftbites.Adapters.OrdersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(OrdersAdapter.java:19)
```

Codes:

**OrdersAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.swiftbites.Adapters;

import ...

public class OrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.viewHolder>{

    ArrayList<OrdersModel> list;
    Context context;

    public OrdersAdapter(ArrayList<OrdersModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.order_sample, parent, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {

        final OrdersModel model = list.get(position);
        holder.orderImage.setImageResource(model.getOrderImage());
        holder.soldItemName.setText(model.getSoldItemName());
        holder.orderNumber.setText(model.getOrderNumber());
        holder.price.setText(model.getPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView orderImage;
        TextView soldItemName, orderNumber, price;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            orderImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderImage);
            soldItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderItemName);
            orderNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do share your order_sample.xml

Comment: @PriyankaRajput Here it is:
https://pastebin.com/v4GngaCx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter you are getting id named **orderPrice** but in defined xml, there is no id defined named as this. This is why you are getting crash. You need to rename **textView6** to  **orderPrice** or you can change  **orderPrice** in adapter to **textView6** as below

change this

```
 price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderPrice);
```

to this

```
 price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
```

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if it worked for you. It will help other too

Answer (score -1):

check your textView id
its is wrong that's why android studio produce null pointer exception Because you setText() on another textView instead of this.